# How do I find the max value in a nested list using a function?

Tags: python

The list given is

```
[["A",3.1],["B",8.90]]
```

I need to print the max value from the list in this statement:

```
B has the highest value of 8.90
```

I tried using this code but it does not work and only returns me ["8"]

```
def maxnumber():
    list=[]
    for letter in values:
        list.append(max(letter[1]))
    return list
print(maxnumber())
```

Comment: First and foremost - don't use `max` or `list` as variable names. You mask the built-ins that way. You named your function `max()` and it's trying to use the built-in function `max()`, which will lead to issues.

Comment: Where is the definition for `maxcategory()`?

Comment: At any rate, your given function (assuming it is named `maxcategory()`) will produce a `TypeError`, not `["8"]`.

Comment: You are using `values` inside you function but you haven't decalared it anywhere. what is `values`? where is `maxcategory()` defined? Also, do not use `list` and `max` as a variable name or do not define them as a function because they are built in functions.

Answer (score 2):

You can acheive this with this code:

```
def get_max(input_list):
    max_list = max(input_list, key=lambda x: x[1])
    return max_list

list_to_check = [["A",3.1],["B",8.90]]
result = get_max(list_to_check)
print(f"{result[0]} has the highest value of {result[1]}")
```

This will print out: "B has the highest value of 8.9"